# jQuery selector - get divs that are the parent of more than one div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all the elements on a page which have multiple divs as child elements. For example, in the following code:

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="1a">
        <div id="1aa">

        </div>
        <div id="1ab">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="1b">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <div id="2b">

    </div>
</div>
```

My function would return `#1` and `#1a` as they both contain 2 child divs.

I've tried this:

```
$('div > div + div').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

But not only does this not work as desired, I also want it to apply when there are 5, 6, 7 /as many as possible child divs, provided it is `>=2`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('div').length >= 2;
}).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively...

```
$("div:has(>div:eq(1))")
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXjy8/).

It would be beneficial to add a comment to this selector to explain its purpose as it's not immediately clear what its intent is.

It's not using standard CSS, so can't delegate straight off to `querySelectorAll()`. If you found it was a performance issue, just split it into its chunks (perhaps using `filter()` to reduce the collection).

Comment: This is a good answer. I should have been more specific in the OP though - can this be altered slightly to only apply to DIRECT children? That is, if div1 has one child, div2, which has 3 divs as children, I'd only want to select div2.

Comment: @AnthonyY See comment above about `>`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aJSbA/

```
if ($('div:has(div)').length) { // this will check if div has child div elem
    $('div > div').css("border", "1px solid red"); // applies css to its direct child
}
```